# How to get to RouteDefinition in Camel 3.x (migration from 2.x to 3.x)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, migration

I upgraded camel-parent from 2.x to 3.x. I had this use in code:

```
 exchange.getContext()
                .getRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId())
                .getRouteContext()
                .getRoute()
                .stop();
```

Now

```
 exchange.getContext()
                .getRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId())
                .getRouteContext()
```

gives us an interface where we cannot get to `org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition` instead we get
`org.apache.camel.NamedNode` on which I cannot execute `stop` method. Could you tell me how can I get to this RouteDefinition so that I can execute `stop` method on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new way to do it (in Camel 3) is to use the `RouteController`, eg:

camelContext.getRouteController().suspendRoute("my-route-id");

Comment: should not I use stopRoute then?

Comment: It was just to illustrate the services (eg suspendRoute) that are available on the RouteController. But yes, in your particular case, you can call stopRoute indeed. You can use startRoute/stopRoute or suspendRoute/resumeRoute